# How to correctly build a directive that trims an input's value?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, form-control

I'm trying to build a simple directive that trims the value of an input field when the `blur` event is fired.

The idea is that I want to make sure that any trailing and leading white spaces are removed, so that data saved is correct. I know I could simply use `trim()` when I save the value prior to sending it on a request; but I'm trying to do it in a directive since I already have a large application with lots of inputs, so it seems easier to just build a directive that I can apply to the inputs.

So far I have this code:

**TrimDirective**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTrim]'
})
export class TrimDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('blur') onBlur() {
    this.el.nativeElement.value.trim();
  }

}
```

**Input Element**

```
 <div class="wsm-card-header d-flex justify-content-end">
      <input appTrim type="text" class="wsm-input">
 </div>
```

However it seems the directive isn't working as it should; if I click outside the input to remove focus, the value in it still has any space I typed in.

I haven't worked much with directives so I'm not sure if there are some caveats, usually any input I have is part of a `ReactiveForm` o just a `FormControl` by itself so I can subscribe to `valueChanges` and the like; but I wanted to know if a directive can do what I'm looking for and if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working a bit more, I noticed simply setting the value of `this.el.nativeElement.value` to be equal to its trimmed value didn't work that well while using `FormControl`, so even if the whitespaces were removed on Blur, the form control's value still had them and could be sent on the request.

So at the end I was able to make it work with `ReactiveForms` by injecting `NgControl` in my directive's constructor and using `NgControl.control.setValue()` to pass the trimmed value, which is great since it triggers the `valueChanges` observable of the `FormControl` and updates its value on blur.

Directive code ends up looking like this:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTrim]'
})
export class TrimDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,  @Optional() private ngControl: NgControl) { }

  @HostListener('blur') onBlur() {
    this.ngControl.control.setValue(this.el.nativeElement.value.trim());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes inside directive

```
@HostListener('blur') onBlur() {
    this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.trim();
  }
```

Comment: Wow, simple enough, thank you! I'll accept the answer in a few minutes